# How to prevent scraping my blog's updates?

Tags: wordpress, web-scraping, clone

I have a self-hosted wordpress blog, and as almost expected, I found there's another blog scraping my contents, posting a perfect copy of my own posts (texts, images not hotlinked but fetched and reupped to the clone's server, html layout within the posts) with a few hours of delay.

however I must confess I'm infuriated to see that when I search Google for keywords relevant to my posts, the scraping clone always comes first.

So, here I am, open for suggestions, would you know how to prevent my site from being successfully scraped ?

Technical precisions :

- the clone blog appears to be self-hosted, and so am I, I'm on a debian+webmin+virtualmin dedi
- my RSS feed is already cut with a "read more on" halfway. Hey, I just thought I should publish a post while assigning it a date like 2001-01-01, and see if it appears on the clone blog, that would allow to know if my RSS is still used as a signal for "hey, it's scraping time !"
- my logs can't find the scraper among legit traffic, either it's non-identifiable or else it's lost among the flood of legit traffic
- I already htaccess-banned and iptables-banned the .com domain of the clone, my contents are still cloned nonetheless
- the clone website makes use of reverse proxies, so I can't trace where it is hosted and what actual IPs should be blocked (well, unless I iptables-ignore-ban half of Europe to ban the whole IP ranges of its data storage facility, but I'm slightly reluctant to that !)
- I'm confident this isn't hand-made, the cloning has been running for two years now, every day without fail
- only my new posts are cloned, not the rest of my website (not the sidebars, not the wordpress pages as opposed to wordpress posts, not the single pages), so setting up a jail.html to log who opens it page won't work, no honey-potting
- when my posts contain internal links pointing to another page of my website, the posts on the clone won't be rewritten and will still point to my own website

I'd love help and suggestions with this issue. Not being cloned, but losing traffic to that bot while I'm the original publisher.

Comment: At a certain level, as long as your website is publicly accessible, you can't stop someone from copying all your content - if someone can read it, someone can copy it. I think your best bet is working on improving your standing with Google - perhaps filing a complaint with them, or making sure you are signed up for Webmaster tools and there is no problem with googlebot scraping/indexing your site, etc.

Comment: I know CURL can recreate Cookies, but can it recreate Sessions? If not, why not only display the page if a valid session is created in the header?

Comment: You could start talking about bananas. only. bananas.

Comment: @maiorano84 Sessions are just an identifier stored in a cookie, so CURL does support sessions.

Comment: @mcrumley You're right, I was grasping at straws.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really stop them in the end, but you might be able to find them and mess with them.  Try hiding the request IP in an HTML comment, or white-on-white text, or just somewhere out of the way, then see what IPs show up on the copies.  You can also try to obfuscate that text if you want by turning it into a hex string or something so it's less obvious to someone who doesn't know or make it look like an error code, just so they don't catch on to what you're doing.

In the end, though, I'm not sure how much it will buy you.  If they're really inattentive, rather than shutting them down and calling attention to the fact that you're onto them, you can feed them gibberish or whatever whenever one of their IPs crops up.  That might be fun and it's not too hard to make a gibberish generator by putting sample texts into a Markov chain.

EDIT:  Oh, and if pages aren't rewritten too much, you might be able to add some inline JS to make them link to you, if they don't strip that.  Say, a banner that only shows up if they're not at your site, giving the original link to your articles and suggesting that people read that.

Comment: Hmm, Qsario, I'm under the impression you think I can make the cloner machine's IP appear somehow ? Or that I can find the cloner's IP already ? Fact is, I don't know that IP :(

Comment: `<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ?>` will display the IP. If they are using a proxy server it will be more complicated, but you can also check for `$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']` and `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']`.

Comment: Oh, you mean to insert this into my blog's posts, in invisible characters ? And doing this would make it so that my post's cloned version would display the IP of the cloner's server ?

Comment: if you drop the code from @mcrumley in your post template (probably single.php), it will show your IP for yours and his IP for his, so it should be different content, provided that he IS stealing from the lowest level he can, DB. if he's scrapping your posts, he won't get the PHP code, and will just copy your IP into his posts because he's just grabbing the output HTML from yours (which would at that point contain your IP)

Comment: The REMOTE_ADDR is the request IP (IP address of the client requesting the page). When the scraper accesses the page it will be the scraper's IP. When you visit the page it will be your own IP.

Comment: Indeed, these guys have it exactly right.  You make it so that the visitor's IP address is hidden somewhere in the blog post (hopefully invisibly).  Then when he copies your posts, his IP gets copied with the rest of the text and you trace him down and feed his scrapers gibberish or perhaps just notices to read the originals with links pointing back to your site, or whatever you want, really.  Ultimately, it will depend on how attentive they are.  If you don't create errors and they do this to everyone, they might not even notice.

Answer (score 0):

Are you willing to shut down your RSS Feed? if so you could do something like

```
function fb_disable_feed() {
wp_die( __('No feed available,please visit our <a href="'. get_bloginfo('url') .'">homepage</a>!') );
}
add_action('do_feed', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rdf', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss2', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_atom', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
```

it means if you go to a feed page, it just returns with the message in `wp_die()` on line two. We use it for 'free' versions of our WP Software with an if-statement so they can't hook into their RSS feeds to link to their main website, it's an upsell opportunity for us, it works well is my point, haha.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is a little old of a post, I thought it would still be helpful for me to weigh in in case other people see the post and have the same question. Since you've eliminated the RSS feed from the mix and youre pretty confident it isnt a manual effort, then what you need to is better stop the bots they are using.

First, I would recommend banning proxy servers in your IPTables. You can get a list of known proxy server addresses from [Maxmind](http://www.maxmind.com). This should limit their ability to anonymize themselves.

Second, it would be great to make it harder for them to scrape. You could accomplish this in one of a couple of ways. You could render part, or all of your site in javascript. If nothing else, you could at least just render the links in javascript. This will make it significantly harder for them to scrape you. Alternatively, you can put your content within an iframe inside the pages. This will also make it somewhat harder to crawl and scrape.

All this said, if they really want your content they will pretty easily get by these traps. Honestly, fighting off webscrapers is an arms race. You cannot put any static trap in place to stop them, instead you have to continuously evolve your tactics.

For full disclosure, I am a co-founder of [Distil Networks](http://www.distilnetworks.com), and we offer an anti-scraping solution as a service.

Comment: Wow, I didn't imagine my old question would receive a reply. You're a bit too late for this, haha. I finally got this problem solved, and here's how : by simply adding cloudflare CDN to my website, as soon as I changed the nameservers at my registrar to use Cloudflare's IPs, the bot stopped scraping my blog. Something must have done the job within cloudflare, but what, I have no idea. Good luck with your business, Rami !

Comment: Thanks! Cloudflare has a built in Web Application Firewall that is able to stop some bots. Glad that you were able to resolve your problem, hopefully others can benefit from your solution :)